# APNS Bad Channel Error on Notification Hub Test Push Send

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

I am developing a cross-platform application with `xamarin forms` and I'm trying to run notifications on the various devices through the `notification hub`.

I encounter a problem when I try to send a test notification for the iphone.

The device can register the token, received by apns, on the notification hub even if only after the '<' and '>' and spaces are deleted, otherwise, the notification hub returns the error "one or more characters in device token is not a hexadecimal digit".

However, when I try to send a first test notification, Notification Hub returns:

> "The test message has been sent. Outcome: {1 success, 0 unsuccessful}"

but notification never reaches the device. All the test notifications sent subsequently result:

> "The test message has been sent. Outcome: {0 success, 0 unsuccessful}"

In fact, going to see the metrics in the notification hub the next day there are some

> "APNS bad Channel Error"

So what could be the problem? Did anyone have the same problem? And what does "APNS bad channel error" mean?

Answer (score 1):

The APNS Bad channel error indicates the device token you are using is no longer valid. Your app on the device needs to update the token on app. You can include that as part of application restart.

Also, regarding the notication not reaching the device. Can you make sure the device is switched on and notification are turned on. You can try to set the apns-expiration header to a longer value so that apns stores the notification for redelivery for a longer time.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW13

Thanks,
Amol